# createRef<View>() giving error react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement drag and drop using [this](https://github.com/benawad/drag-n-drop-flatlist/blob/master/Rec.tsx) tutorial. In this tutorial i have to create a refs like this `list = createRef<RecyclerListView<any, any>>()` (line no 55), which is giving me `syntex error: unexpected token`. What i understand is that, they are using .tsx extension (don't know what for) but i'm using .js extension, which maybe the reason why this code not working in my end, and not finding any solution of that. Can anyone help me out on that? Thank you

Comment: dont use types in js file. or use typescript for using types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.tsx` extension is for Typescript files. Javascript is not a typed language. To put it simply, Typescript was built to make Javascript look like a typed language. Whatever you put in `<>` after `createRef`, specifies the type of the ref that is being created and you can only use types in Typescript files (`.ts` and `.tsx`). If you want to move to Typescript, you'll have to do [some setup](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-React-Conversion-Guide) and change your file extensions to `.tsx`. Otherwise, if you'd like to stay on `.js`, just ignore the types in the tutorial and instead write `list = createRef()`.

Comment: $griotskhada Thanks for your reply. No i don't want to move to typescript. my above example are getting a references of RecyclerListView, will it do that same here! because i'm not mentioning anything here.. can you be more specific about it?

Comment: Yes, the ref will be set to a reference of the element which you pass it as a `ref` prop to. So, if you pass this `list` to `<RecyclerListView ref={list} />`, then it will be a ref of `RecyclerListView`. You don't need to specify the type.